# VSCode Wrap HTML attributes each on their own line

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

I'm looking for a setting or extension in VSCode that provides the following functionality:

- Format on save
- wrap html attributes on their own line, even if there is only one attribute
- put closing symbol of opening tag on new line, aligned with tag
- alphabetically order attributes
- do not align attributes according to the position of the first attribute, simple use one level of indentation

Example 1:

```html
<span my-attr="value">Hello, world!</span>
```

becomes

```html
<span
    my-attr="value"
>
    Hello, world!
</span>
```

Example 2:

```html
<x-status-indicator wire:click="pushMe" class="block" :status="$status" 
    :description="$description" />
```

then becomes

```html
<x-status-indicator
    :description="$description"
    :status="$status"
    class="block"
    wire:click="pushMe"
/>
```

So far there have been many posts about formatting, but I could not find a single post or extension that satisfies these requirements. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is provided by default HTML formatter.

Settings > Search for `html.format.wrapAttributes` > set it to `force-expand-multiline`

[image: html.format.wrapAttributes]

Your example would become:

Before format:

```html
<x-status-indicator wire:click="pushMe" class="block" :status="$status" 
    :description="$description" />
```

After format:

```html
<x-status-indicator
    wire:click="pushMe"
    class="block"
    :status="$status"
    :description="$description"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like they added that after I posted the question. One remaining issue: they don't put attributes on their own line if there is only a single attribute. any suggestions for that?